# Adding the values of two strings using Python and XML path

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

It generates an output with wallTime and setupwalltime into a dat file, which has the following format:

```
24000   4       0
81000   17      0
192000  59      0
648000  250     0
1536000 807     0
3000000 2144    0
6591000 5699    0
```

I would like to know how to add the two values i.e.(wallTime and setupwalltime) together. Can someone give me a hint? I tried converting to float, but it doesn’t seem to work.

```
import libxml2
import os.path
from numpy import *
from cfs_utils import *

np=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
n=[20,30,40,60,80,100,130]
solver=["BiCGSTABL_iluk", "BiCGSTABL_saamg", "BiCGSTABL_ssor" ,  "CG_iluk", "CG_saamg", "CG_ssor" ]# ,"cholmod", "ilu" ]
file_list=["eval_BiCGSTABL_iluk_default",  "eval_BiCGSTABL_saamg_default" , "eval_BiCGSTABL_ssor_default" ,  "eval_CG_iluk_default","eval_CG_saamg_default", "eval_CG_ssor_default" ] # "simp_cholmod_solver_3D_evaluate", "simp_ilu_solver_3D_evaluate" ]

for cnt_np in np:
    i=0
    for sol in solver:
            #open write_file= "Graphs/" +  "Np"+ cnt_np + "/CG_iluk.dat"
            #"Graphs/Np1/CG_iluk.dat"


            write_file = open("Graphs/"+ "Np"+ str(cnt_np) + "/" + sol + ".dat", "w")
            print("Reading " + "Graphs/"+ "Np"+ str(cnt_np) + "/" + sol + ".dat"+ "\n")

            #loop through different unknowns
            for cnt_n in n:

                    #open file "cfs_calculations_" + cnt_n +"np"+ cnt_np+ "/" +  file_list(i) + "_default.info.xml"

                    read_file = "cfs_calculations_" +str(cnt_n) +"np"+ str(cnt_np) + "/" +  file_list[i] + ".info.xml"
                    print("File list" + file_list[i] + "vlaue of  i  " + str(i) + "\n")
                    print("Reading " + " cfs_calculations_" +str(cnt_n) +"np"+ str(cnt_np) + "/" +  file_list[i] + ".info.xml" )
                    #read wall and cpu time and write

                    if os.path.exists(read_file):
                            doc = libxml2.parseFile(read_file)
                            xml = doc.xpathNewContext()

                            walltime = xpath(xml, "//cfsInfo/sequenceStep/OLAS/mechanic/solver/summary/solve/timer/@wall")
                            setupwalltime = xpath(xml, "//cfsInfo/sequenceStep/OLAS/mechanic/solver/summary/setup/timer/@wall")
                    #       cputime = xpath(xml, "//cfsInfo/sequenceStep/OLAS/mechanic/solver/summary/solve/timer/@cpu")
                    #       setupcputime = xpath(xml, "//cfsInfo/sequenceStep/OLAS/mechanic/solver/summary/solve/timer/@cpu")
                            unknowns = 3*cnt_n*cnt_n*cnt_n
                            write_file.write(str(unknowns) + "\t" + walltime + "\t" + setupwalltime + "\n")
                            print("Writing_point" + str(unknowns) + "%f" ,float(setupwalltime  ) )
                            doc.freeDoc()
                            xml.xpathFreeContext()
            write_file.close()
            i=i+1
```

Comment: what's the error you get? exception+traceback please

Comment: write_file.write(str(unknowns) + "\f" + float(walltime) + float(setupwalltime) + "\n")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Comment: Just `str()`ing the float sum does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you can add strings and floats. What I understand is that you need to add the values and then display them. That would work (stringing the sum)

```
write_file.write(str(unknowns) + "\f" + str(float(walltime) + float(setupwalltime)) + "\n")
```

Comment: 24000^L4.0
      81000^L17.0
     192000^L59.0
     648000^L250.0
    1536000^L807.0
     3000000^L2144.0
    6591000^L5699.0 this is the output which i Got now

Comment: That's because you were using `\f` for tabulations and I did not correct that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add a `str` to a `float`. That doesn't work. If you want to use string concatenation, first coerce all of the values to `str`.  Try this:

```
write_file.write(str(unknowns) + "\t" + str(float(walltime) + float(setupwalltime)) + "\n")
```

Or, perhaps more readably:

```
totalwalltime = float(walltime) + float(setupwalltime)
write_file.write("{}\t{}\n".format(unknowns, totalwalltime))
```

Comment: It saved my time. Thanks for the help!